# How can i get the same layout as used in Keep app (by google)?

Tags: android

I am working on one android app and i want kind of listview as used in keep app. i have tried to search this thing on google but it didn't find any thing similar.

If any one has any idea or link then please let me know.

Thanks in advance :).

please find attached picture of listview which is used in keep application.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K21QR.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) with GridLayoutManager with 2 columns. You can use [CardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView) for the list items.